# I am encountering a persistent issue with the connection pool being cleared when I connect to a MongoDB replica set using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have set up a MongoDB replica set with three nodes using Docker Desktop as follows:

```
docker run -d --name mongo-primary --net mongo-cluster -p 27017:27017 mongo:4.0 --replSet rs0
docker run -d --name mongo-secondary1 --net mongo-cluster mongo:4.0 --replSet rs0
docker run -d --name mongo-secondary2 --net mongo-cluster mongo:4.0 --replSet rs0
```

```
rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: 'rs0',
    members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "mongo-primary:27017" },
      { _id: 1, host: "mongo-secondary1:27017" },
      { _id: 2, host: "mongo-secondary2:27017" }
    ]
  }
)
```

The replica set nodes appear to be in a normal state, and I can consistently connect to them using MongoDB Compass from my local machine. However, when I attempt to connect to the replica set from IntelliJ IDEA and execute the Document userInfo = adminDatabase.runCommand(command); command, I consistently encounter an error. Interestingly, when I debug the code, the error doesn't always occur, indicating an unstable connection. I have verified the network connectivity, and MongoDB Compass can reliably connect to the replica set, and the replica set status is also normal.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://mongo-primary:27017,mongo-secondary1:27017,mongo-secondary2:27017/?replicaSet=rs0");

        // 创建MongoClientSettings
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .applyToSocketSettings(builder ->
                        builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                        builder.serverSelectionTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();

        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings)) {
            MongoDatabase adminDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin");


//            try {
//                Bson command = new BsonDocument("dbStats", new BsonInt64(1));
//                // Retrieves statistics about the specified database
//                Document commandResult = adminDatabase.runCommand(command);
//                // Prints the database statistics
//                System.out.println("dbStats: " + commandResult.toJson());
//            } catch (MongoException me) {
//                // Prints a message if any exceptions occur during the command execution
//                System.err.println("An error occurred: " + me);
//            }

            Document command = new Document("usersInfo", "admin");
            Document userInfo = adminDatabase.runCommand(command);
            System.out.println(userInfo.toJson());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

```
    10:50:19.082 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=mongo-primary:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=mongo-secondary2:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=mongo-secondary1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
10:50:19.083 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool for mongo-primary:27017 cleared
10:50:19.085 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary1:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Discovered replica set primary mongo-secondary1:27017 with max election id 7fffffff000000000000001a and max set version 1
10:50:19.085 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=mongo-primary:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=mongo-secondary2:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=mongo-secondary1:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, roundTripTime=40.8 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
10:50:19.085 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary2:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool ready for mongo-secondary2:27017
10:50:19.086 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary2:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Rediscovering type of existing primary mongo-secondary1:27017
10:50:19.086 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary2:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=mongo-primary:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=mongo-secondary2:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=mongo-secondary1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
10:50:19.086 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary2:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool for mongo-secondary1:27017 cleared
10:50:19.086 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary2:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Discovered replica set primary mongo-secondary2:27017 with max election id 7fffffff000000000000001a and max set version 1
10:50:19.087 [cluster-ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}-mongo-secondary2:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=mongo-primary:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=mongo-secondary2:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, roundTripTime=40.8 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=mongo-secondary1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
10:50:19.087 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Checkout failed for connection to mongo-primary:27017. Reason: An error occurred while trying to establish a new connection. Error: com.mongodb.MongoConnectionPoolClearedException: Connection pool for ServerId{clusterId=ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}, address=mongo-primary:27017} is paused
10:50:19.089 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool closed for mongo-primary:27017
10:50:19.093 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool closed for mongo-secondary2:27017
10:50:19.094 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Connection pool closed for mongo-secondary1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoConnectionPoolClearedException: Connection pool for ServerId{clusterId=ClusterId{value='65b863ea7a721c34f2bfec71', description='null'}, address=mongo-primary:27017} is paused
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$StateAndGeneration.lambda$pauseAndIncrementGeneration$0(DefaultConnectionPool.java:1521)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool$StateAndPermits.throwIfClosedOrPaused(ConcurrentPool.java:498)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool$StateAndPermits.acquirePermitImmediateUnfair(ConcurrentPool.java:372)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.getImmediateUnfair(ConcurrentPool.java:172)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.getPooledConnectionImmediateUnfair(DefaultConnectionPool.java:342)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.access$1800(DefaultConnectionPool.java:124)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.acquirePermitOrGetAvailableOpenedConnection(DefaultConnectionPool.java:1026)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openWithConcurrencyLimit(DefaultConnectionPool.java:936)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openOrGetAvailable(DefaultConnectionPool.java:888)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:185)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:96)
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:186)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:204)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:362)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$1(OperationHelper.java:344)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:370)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:343)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$executeRetryableRead$7(CommandOperationHelper.java:225)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$decorateReadWithRetries$3(CommandOperationHelper.java:192)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeRetryableRead(CommandOperationHelper.java:230)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeRetryableRead(CommandOperationHelper.java:212)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandReadOperation.execute(CommandReadOperation.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:153)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.executeCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:165)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:160)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:150)
    at com.chinatelecom.dts.manager.biz.channel.precheckitem.MongoTest.main(MongoTest.java:57)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The error consistently occurs at the line Document userInfo = adminDatabase.runCommand(command); every time，

I don't know how to resolve it; I've checked everything I should